# Why does Pycharm have orange files?

Tags: windows, pandas, python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to import pandas, and I am getting errors because the file for pandas is orange. I looked up the error, and it says something about being deleted so I reinstalled but I am still getting an error. The errors are "no module named pandas" and "unused import statement." I am using python 2.7, pip 10.0.1,anaconda2,pandas 2.7.3

Can someone please help? I am new, and if you give step-by-step information it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The python folders were orange to reflect that the system is not using those folders and you can turn them back on to use the folder. So orange off and grey on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using python env with pandas ? You can check more if you go to `File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter` . From there, you can select python envs you have, install manually packages and so on.

Example of an interface:

[image: Project interpreter]

With **+** sign, you can add some packages, just search them and click install.

With **gear** or **cog** icon you can add new python enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same issue with the Pillow Module. Even if it was installed successfully, Pycharm wouldn't let me use it and actually in ***Extrernal LIbraries*** -> ***Lib***, the file ***site-packages*** was orange. I just opened a new project and i checked the following as it is shown in the picture. I don't know how  this works exactly , but when it works it works! XD

Check the Inherit global site-packages as it is shown in this picture. click [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOKVs.png)